# SharePoint Products Configuration Failing - Win32Exception : The data area passed to a system call is too small

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard

Server A was connected to farm A. I uninstalled SharePoint and installed again to create farm B in the same SQL Server.

The SharePoint installation is successfull, however when I try to run the configuration wizard to create the config database (from gui or console) I get the following error and stack trace:

```
An exception of type System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown.        Additonal excption information: 
 The data area passed to a system call is too small.
 at   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.
 SPServer.GrantRevokeReadAccessToSCManagerAndCryptSvc
```

In the ULS log, the error that I'm seeing is this:

```
Ensuring WSS_WPG read access to cryptsvc service.
Failed to open cryptsvc service: 122
```

After a bit of reserve engineering, I got the excat system call that is failing:

```
Advapi32.OpenService(sPServiceSafeHandle, "CRYPTSVC", 393216u)
```

I tried the following to solve my issue:

- Ensuring setup account rights (SQL sysadmin, machine administrators group, etc.)
- Reinstalling SharePoint (again)
- Changing setup account to my own domain account
- Deleted WSS_WPG local groups
- Restarting machine, restarting cryptographic service
- Enabling randomly windows disabled services
- Uninstalling SharePoint updates and tried RTM release

Not working, what now do except try to wipe and recreate VM?

Comment: did you perform complete uninstall the sharepoint from server?also make sure following permission for wss-wpg https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx#Section5

Comment: make sure WSS-WPG having permission on wind\system32 folder.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes I did a complete uninstall/reinstall from the server. It says on the technet link that the configuration should grant those permissions to WSS-WPG. I must grant them manually to the folders before the configuration is ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by removing all GPOs on this particular machine and rebooting.